# Currying function does not update

Tags: javascript, currying, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a currying function in JavaScript,the inner function does not update the value of the array args:

```
var myCurry=function(fn)
{
    var len=fn.length;
    var _slice=Array.prototype.slice;
    var args=_slice.call(arguments,1);
    console.log(args.length);
    return function next()
    {
        var rem=_slice.call(arguments,0)
        args.concat(rem);
        console.log(args.length);
        if(len<=args.length)
            return fn.apply(null,args);
        else
            return next;
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
 var _sum=myCurry(sum,2);
 var res=_sum(2);
 var res2=res(3,4);
 console.log(res2);
```

This returns the function next at all times,presumably because the array is not updated.How do I fix this error to ensure that the function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops:

```
args.concat(rem);
```

Instead:

```
args = args.concat(rem);
```

`concat()` performs no in-place modifications. It returns a new `Array`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `.concat()` doesn't mutate the array. Use `.push()` instead if you want to mutate the original.

```
args.push.apply(args, rem);
```

---

Or if you didn't care if the original was replaced, just assign the return value from `.concat()`

```
args = args.concat(rem);
```

Comment: Using push causes the numbers to be converted to String,and performing addition causes the result to appear like this: `223,4`.Is push type-coercive?

Comment: @user2309862: No, there's no conversion when using `.push()`. The issue must be elsewhere. Did you type it exactly as I have, using `.apply()`? If not, then that's most likely your issue. If you did `args.push(rem)`, then that's very different from doing `args.push.apply(args, rem);`, which is what my answer shows.

Comment: I tried it out using node,that was when I got the output I mentioned above

Comment: @user2309862: It doesn't matter if it's in NodeJS or in a browser. It does matter if you did `args.push.apply(args, rem)` vs `args.push(rem)`... and by the way, if you use `.push()` correctly like that, you don't even need to `_slice()` the `arguments`. Just do `args.push.apply(args, arguments);`